# How to test that method waits for asynchronous calls to complete

Tags: multithreading, junit

I want to confirm that a method waits on an asynchronous thread to complete before exiting.

The method looks something like this:

```
public void methodToTest() {

    AsyncTaskExecutor executor = MyTaskExecutor.getInstance();
    MyTask asyncTask = new MyTask(); // implements Runnable
    Future<?> future = executor.submit(asyncTask);

    ...do something

    future.get();
}
```

I could mock the async task to take a certain amount of time, but that would slow down the unit tests. I could verify that future.get() is called, but if get() actually did nothing, my test would still pass (but maybe my test should just assume it works as expected, which it does). Is there a better way to test that this method waits for the async thread to complete?

Comment: what method are you testing, actually? The method Future::get? Why?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov For context, we ran into an issue where a resource was being deleted before the asynchronous thread was able to use it. To prevent that from happening, this method should wait on the asynchronous thread to finish before the code proceeds. I am trying to add some kind of test to make sure this wait happens.